# Spin state of photons inside laser

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, laser, quantum-optics

Can the total spin state of photons inside a laser beam be written as a product of individual spin states ? Tentatively, the answer seems to be yes because single laser beam have a definite polarization state.

So, is it possible that N-photon spin state inside a laser beam be entangled ?

Can such entanglement arise when we consider multiple laser beams with distinct polarizations colliding at a focal spot ?

I would appreciate if someone could provide reading material on the subject.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: @my2cts there two questions really..I did not want to open up a new post for the second one since it is closely related to the first question.